# Finding minima and maxima of a surface in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, polynomials

I have just started using MATLAB. I want to find the minima and maxima of this 2nd degree polynomial surface.

```
f(x,y) = 4490  + 8902*x + 1.385e+05*y + 9.497*x^2 + -9928*x*y + 1.481e+05*y^2;
```

I know how to calculate minima and maxima for a degree 1 function but I wasn't able to get any lead regarding higher degree functions. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluate the function for `x` and all `y` and find the `min`/`max` of that matrix:

```
x1D = 1:100;
y1D = 1:100;

[x,y] = meshgrid(x1D,y1D);
f = 4490  + 8902*x + 1.385e+05*y + 9.497*x.^2 + -9928.*x.*y + 1.481e+05*y.^2;

[minV, minL] = min(f(:));
[maxV, maxL] = max(f(:));

[minX, minY] = ind2sub(size(f),minL);
[maxX, maxY] = ind2sub(size(f),maxL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets first define a range for x,y which you want to find minima.Then make a mesh grid which is basically a matrix containing those x and y as coordinates. Then evaluate the function at all those points as z which is also a matrix. Each member of z is at the position similar to x and y as input. Then find the location of minimum value for z matrix. The last 2 command should give you the position coordinates where the minima happened.

```
x=1:100;
y=1:100;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y); % 
z = 4490  + X.*8902 + Y.*1.385e+05 +X.^2*9.497 X.*Y.*9928+Y.^2*1.48e+05;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
surf(x,y,z) % plotting the curve
[Row,Col]=find(z==min(min(z)))
x(Row) % x coordinate
y(Col) % y coordinate
```